# Insert k copies of each element in ArrayList

Tags: java

This method takes an `ArrayList<String> s` and `int k` , then creates `k` copies of each element.

```
public static void copyStrings(ArrayList<String> s, int k) {
        if (k <= 0) {
            s.clear();
        } else {
            int limit = s.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                for( int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                    s.add(s.get(i));
                }    
            }
            for( int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                s.remove(0);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have double the indenting that you should inside your method.

Rather than calling `s.get(i)` every time, store it in a variable and use from that instead. Incidentally, this means that you can use an advanced `for` instead of a simple one.

I'd recommend renaming `limit` to `originalSize`, so that it's clear what it is.

`s` isn't descriptive. Why not call it `source`? Ditto with `k` -- why not call it `copies`?

Why are you making it specific to `String`s, when it's almost just a find-and-replace away from being a generic method? If you make it generic, it'll work with any type, not just the one.

Aside from that, there's not much. Your code is pretty short, and there isn't much to say. Here's your code with these tips applied:

```
public static <E> void copyStrings(ArrayList<E> source, int copies) {
    if (copies <= 0) {
        source.clear();
    } else {
        int limit = source.size();
        for(E element : source) {
            for( int j = 0; j < copies; j++) {
                source.add(element);
            }    
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            source.remove(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use an `Iterator` and  `remove` the element before making copies. This would greatly simplify the logic.

Answer (score 7):

A negative number of copies is nonsense. Simply ignoring it is "garbage in, garbage out" policy, which is not good. A negative number indicates a programming error in the caller, and it's best to catch such errors as early as possible. If you don't, the problem can manifest much later as an obscure bug, extremely hard to debug. In such situations it's good to crash the program spectacularly so the problem is noticed. A common solution to that effect is to throw an illegal argument exception.

Removing elements from the front of an array list one by one is not efficient. For each removed element, the entire rest of the array list is copied one position to the left. If you don't mind using a little extra memory, a more optimal solution will be to make a copy of the original array list, then clear the original, and iterate over the copy to insert elements the required number of times.

Comment: Exactly the points which came to my mind

Answer (score 5):

Four minor points:

*Clearing* the input `ArrayList` (and really, that should be a `List` unless you are targeting the *implementing* class for some reason) when `k`/`copies` is equal to or less than zero should be clearly documented as a Javadoc, following the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). In fact, I think the alternative of throwing some kind of `Exception` might work better too.

You don't need the `else` actually, since the main work is  already the second and final clause of the current `if`-block. To borrow from [@QPaysTaxes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/95172/27975) answer:

```
public static <E> void copyStrings(ArrayList<E> source, int copies) {
    if (copies <= 0) {
        source.clear();
        return;
    }
    int limit = source.size();
    // ...
}
```

Consider returning the `source` as well, to make for slightly more fluent programming? For example, callers can then do something like:

```
// true
boolean doubleSize = copyStrings(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton("A")), 2).size() == 2;
```

Finally, remember your unit testing. :)

Answer (score 5):

The word "copy" implies an operation that is non-mutating and non-destructive.  When I copy something, I expect to have my original and something new.

Allow for the case that no copies are generated.  It shouldn't be an error if I ask for 0 copies, just give me back my original object and an empty container.

If I pass in a *k > 0* as my number of `copies`, I would expect some container with a bunch of copies of my original object.  Not one extra copy to account for the original, but *k* copies.  I actually prefer a container of multiple copies of my original element, as I can then decide whether I want to append the various copies or interweave each individual element.

If my `k < 0`, this is an exceptional situation of user input error, and should handled appropriately.

```
public static ArrayList<String> copyStrings(ArrayList<String> s, int k) {
  ArrayList<String> result;

  if (k < 0) {
    // Handle it.
  } else if (k > 0) {
    while(k--) {
      result.addAll(s);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

public static ArrayList<String> stableCopyStrings(ArrayList<String> s, int k) {
  ArrayList<String> result;

  if (k < 0) {
    // Handle it.
  } else if (k > 0) {
    for (int i = 0, size = limit; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
        result.add(s.get(i));
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that:

1. The names of arguments are not verbose The name of the method
   indicates creating a new list
2. The list doesn't have to be
   parametrised
3. The list's implementation is not important
4. Removing
   items from the beginning of an array causes copying of all latter
   items, which is ineffective

I assume, that you DO want negative number of copies to act like a 0.

Here's my proposition:

```
public static <T> void multiplyList(List<T> list, int copies) {
    final List<T> listCopy = new ArrayList<>(list);
    list.clear();
    for(T item : listCopy)
        for(int i = 0; i < copies; i++) {
            list.add(item);
        }    
    }
}
```